# but Clyde wouldn’t say

Tags: phrase-meaning

Raskin, who sits on a select committee investigating the attack, first grilled Clyde over whether he watched a hearing earlier in the day in which four law enforcement officers recounted their harrowing Jan. 6 experiences – **but Clyde wouldn’t say**.

Source: [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/andrewsolender/2021/07/28/gop-rep-clyde-defends-comparing-jan-6-to-normal-tourist-visit-during-explosive-exchange/?sh=7ab6e8ea506d)

I understand "but Clyde wouldn’t say" as "but Clyde had no intention to reply this question." Am I on the right track?

Comment: Clyde wouldn't say *whether he had watched it*.

Comment: *He wouldn't do it = He **refused** to do it,* which isn't quite the same as saying he ***had no intention*** of doing it (note that *no intention **to** do it* is idiomatically unlikely, if not "syntactically invalid"). Compare *I offered him a good price, but he **wouldn't buy it / had no intention of buying it*** - where ***wouldn't*** could imply that perhaps he *would* have bought it if I'd offered an even lower price, but the ***no intention*** version suggests he wouldn't have wanted to buy it at *any* price (maybe he wouldn't even want it as a free gift! :)

Comment: Thank you.  @FumbleFingers: Please make your reply the answer - make it in the form of Answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's about saying not doing.

Comment: @Lambie: No, it's about the meaning of ***wouldn't*** - it's irrelevant whether he wouldn't ***say*** something or wouldn't ***do*** it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why do you start your explanation with a completely unrelated example?? These comments are hard to understand. Why not just say "wouldn't [verb]" can mean "have no intention of [verb+ing]?

Answer (score 1):

*He **wouldn't** do it = He **refused** to do it*, which isn't quite the same as saying he had *no intention* of doing it. Note that *no intention **to do** it* is idiomatically unlikely, if not "syntactically invalid".

Compare *I offered him a good price, but he **wouldn't buy it / had no intention of buying it*** - where ***wouldn't*** could imply that perhaps he *would* have bought it if I'd offered an even lower price, but the ***no intention*** version suggests he wouldn't have wanted to buy it at *any* price (maybe he wouldn't even want it as a free gift! :)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase here means "Clyde would not say (if he had watched the hearing in question)."